# Importing redux action makes other actions undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is one of the strangest things I have ever seen. It makes absolutely no sense to me. The short version is I have a Redux action creator function. If I import this function into this one particular component file, it makes every function imported from its file undefined.

So, let's start with the file filterInputModal.actions.js. This contains my Redux action functions, created using redux-starter-kit:

```
export const showAddCategoryModal = createAction('showAddCategoryModal');
```

That is the function I've been working with. Now, this function has long since been imported into my ManageVideoFilters.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { showAddCategoryModal } from 'store/filterInputModal/filterInputModal.actions';

const ManageVideoFilters = (props) => {
    /* Component logic */
};

/* PropTypes and mapStateToProps */

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
    showAddCategoryModal: () => showAddCategoryModal() // Done this way to avoid passing in a payload, since certain default event payloads cause Redux to print console errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageVideoFilters);
```

So far so good. Before we go and break everything, let's take a look at my filterInputModal.reducer.js Redux reducer, also created using Redux Starter Kit:

```
import { createReducer } from 'redux-starter-kit';
import { showAddCategoryModal } from './filterInputModal.actions';

const initialState = {}; // The initial state for the reducer goes here

const handleShowAddCategoryModal = (state) => {
    /* handle updating the state */
    return state;
};

const actionMap = {
    [showAddCategoryModal]: handleShowAddCategoryModal
};

export default createReducer(initialState, actionMap);
```

The action map uses the action creator functions toString() as the key, and then I provide my own functions to handle updating the state. Again, at this point, everything is perfect. We will come back to the reducer in a sec, first let's break things.

Now we're going to my VideFileEdit.js component. If we add the following line to this component, everything breaks:

```
import { showAddCategoryModal } from 'store/filterInputModal/filterInputModal.actions';
```

So, how does it break?

1. The import of the showAddCategoryModal function in filterInputModal.reducer.js now is undefined.
2. Because the reducer is using the functions as the keys to handle actions, the reducer is no longer able to handle the action properly and update the state.

It gets weirder though. Here are some of the weird behaviors I'm seeing.

1. If I import this action into any other component, everything is fine. The import in the reducer is unchanged.
2. The import of the function in both ManageVideoFilters.js and VideoFileEdit.js is fine.

So, what can I try next? This is really strange and doesn't make any sense to me. I've never seen this before.

Comment: are there any recursive imports , in your files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenter said, the problem was recursive imports. My filterInputModal.reducer.js exported some constants, which were imported into my filterInputModal.actions.js. The actions from filterInputModal.actions.js were then imported into filterInputModal.reducer.js. Hence the recursive import.

I moved the constants into a new file, filterInputModal.constants.js, and viola, problem solved.